Basis of eigenfunctions and spectrum
I have a linear, closed and densely defined operator $A$ defined on a Hilbert space $H$. I prove that the point spectrum consists of discrete eigenvalues, and that the eigenfunctions of $A$ and of $A^*$ are two biorthonormal basis of $H$.
Moreover, there is no accumulation point in the point spectrum.
Can we deduce from this that the spectrum of $A$ is given by its point spectrum ?

Yes, what have you tried to prove it?

I have the intuition that the spectrum is given by the closure of the point spectrum, but I didn't manage to prove it.
